# rosparam load all yaml-files in folder

Tags: ros, roslaunch, yaml, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, is it possible to load all yaml-files in an folder?
Like:

```
<rosparam folder="$(find parameter)/my_params/" />
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192011/rosparam-load-all-yaml-files-in-folder/) by [Tobias Neumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5908/tobias-neumann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 179 on 2014-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [roslaunch doc](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam) it shouldn't work: "The  tag can either reference a YAML file or contain raw YAML text."
You could try writing a small node that takes a path and uses [rosparam.load_file()](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/indigo-devel/tools/rosparam/src/rosparam/__init__.py#L153)

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2014-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tobias Neumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5908/tobias-neumann/) on 2014-09-05**:
Yes I thought about that too, but I thought there might be an easier solution.

But if I write a node, how can I guarantee that all parameters are loaded before my launch file startes the next node that is depending on them?

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2014-09-05**:
One solution would be to offer a service once all parameters are set and to make the other nodes wait for that service to become available before doing anything.

**Comment by [Tobias Neumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5908/tobias-neumann/) on 2014-09-05**:
Mh, that would work, but needs more codeing than adding a line for each yaml file in the launch file :(

There might be an different way? Would be a cool feature for rosparam

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2014-09-06**:
We are actually following a database approach to that. In my project we are using mongodb and have a tool that reads yaml files, saves the found parameters in the datacentre and also sets them on the parameter server. You can have a look at [this](https://github.com/strands-project/mongodb_store)